# Evaluation of double integral $I=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{x^2} \sqrt{x^2-y}\,dy\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, multiple-integral

I have the following double integral before me:

$$I=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{x^2} \sqrt{x^2-y}\,dy\,dx$$

I got the answer of this integral as $0$ working in the following manner:

$$I=\int_{-1}^{1} \dfrac{-2}{3}(x^2-y)^\frac{3}{2}dx
=\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{2}{3}x^3 dx$$

As $x^3$ is an odd function of $x$, $I$ must be zero.

But when I used Wolfram alpha to find the value of the integral, I instead got $\frac{1}{3}$ as the answer.
I am not able to make out which one is correct and why. Please suggest.

Comment: I suspect that you made a simplification like $(x^2)^{3/2} \to x^3$, which is only valid if $x\geq0$.

Comment: The inner integral is 
$$
\Big[-\frac{2}{3}(|x|^2-y)^\frac{3}{2}\Big]_{y=0}^{y=x^2}=\frac{2}{3}|x|^3.
$$

Comment: A good way of sanity checking this integral is to look at $\int_0^{x^2}\sqrt{x^2-y}dy$ and ask oneself if this can possibly be an odd function. Nice question !

Comment: You can save yourself some sign troubles by noting the integrand is even in $x$, so you can integrate $2\int_0^1$ instead of $\int_{-1}^1$.

Comment: @Kurt G. This is definitely an even function of $x$ as only even powers of $x$ are there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your error is when simplifying $(x^2)^\frac{3}{2}$, this simplifies to $|x|^3$ and thus will be an even function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have,
$$\begin{align} &\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{x^2}\sqrt{x^2- y}\ dy  dx\\=&\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{-2(x^2 -y)^{3/2}}{3}\bigg|^{x^2}_0 dx\\=&\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{-2(x^2 -x^2)^{3/2}}{3} + \dfrac{2(x^2 - 0)^{3/2}}{3}dx\\=&\int_{-1}^10 + \dfrac{2(x^2)^{3/2}}{3}dx\\=&2\int_{0}^1 \dfrac{2(x^2)^{3/2}}{3}dx\qquad\rm{As \ it \ is \ an \ even\ function.}\\=&\dfrac43\int_{0}^1x^3dx\\=&\dfrac43\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)\\= &\dfrac13\end{align}$$